# Difference between dieses und dies in accusative

Tags: pronoun

I was asked to translate the following sentence

> I write this book

And what I wrote is

> Ich schreibe dies Buch

But then I got corrected, and told that the right translation is

> Ich schreibe dieses Buch

It was my understanding that in accusative and nominative for neuter objects, both options could be used. Did I misunderstand?
Are there any rules as to when apply one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was my understanding that in accusative und nominative, for neutrum objects, both options could be used. Did I misundertood?

No your understanding is correct. But *dies* won't be used in colloquial language.
It's a bit old fashioned, and more likely to appear in literature or poetry.

> Is there any rules as to when apply one or the other?

Just like mentioned above, you won't use *dies* in colloquial language, journal articles or technical writing.

Comment: Does that mean that, strictly speaking, my answer was still correct?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Depends a bit on context as mentioned, but strictly spoken your answer would be still correct.